# prevent regex matches both ahead and behind with lookarounds?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match a command through voice recognition on android. The recognition is fine but I'm running into trouble with crafting one of my regex patterns (the program uses java.util.regex)

I have a command that stops my music. It matches anytime stop or kill is in the same command as the word music. It looks like this:

```
((stop|kill).*music)|(music.*(stop|kill))
```

not very pretty, I know but it works

My problem is that I can't formulate the opposite expression:*i.e.* match the term music only if the words stop or kill are not present anywhere in the command. I've been looking at and trying to understand negative look-arounds but they're confusing the hell out of me

I've managed to prevent matches with look-ahead using something like this:

```
music(?!.*(stop|kill))
```

This prevents matches whenever stop or kill shows up after "music" but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it work with a negative lookbehind. I think that maybe my wildcards in the look behind are messing everything up, but I really have no idea.

I'm feeling very stupid and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about first checking if command doesn't contain `stop|kill` with negative-lookahead and then checking if it have `music` with positive look-ahead?

```
^(?!.*(stop|kill))(?=.*music).*
```

Answer (score 1):

Without look-behinds, you can use this regex to match anything that has `music` but has no `stop`/`kill`:

```
(?!.*(stop|kill)).*music.*
```

Results:

```
"stop music"    -> matches() == false
"music stop"    -> matches() == false
"music go"      -> matches() == true
"go music"      -> matches() == true
"music go stop" -> matches() == false
```

Sampling code used:

```
String[] words = {"stop music", "music stop", "music go", "go music", "music go stop" };
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println("\""+word+"\" -> matches() == "+(word.matches("(?!.*(stop|kill)).*music.*")));   
}
```

Comment: That makes an _insane_ amount of sense. I feel slow.